# Moodle - Hide block of Miscellaneous and Login activity

Tags: authentication, show-hide, moodle

I want to hide  Miscellaneous and Login activity block from User profile of moodle and add change password option. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 2 blocks cannot be removed by customizing the profile page. This can be achieved by editing the source code.

Comment: Although it is a bad code choice, but i hide it through css

Comment: Yes, its not good to edit the source code, but some customization demand it. Please don't forget to port the changes when changing the theme.